# Player unable to move after being teleported/transported Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to fix this one bug in my code for over 7 hours now, upon being teleported, the movement controls cease to function, the mouse works fine, you can look around, but you can't move around.

I wanted to set up some simple code that would teleport the player to a "checkpoint" upon achieving a negative or null y level. I was doing this for a parkour based game, if the player fell off the platform they would have to start over, but after teleporting, it becomes impossible to move as I'm sure I have already said. My code is pretty simple:

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
    float Fall;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 Checkpoint = new Vector3 (0,3,0);
        GameObject Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        Fall = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position.y;
        if (Fall<-4) 
        {
            Player.transform.position = Checkpoint;
        }
    }
}
```

You would think that this would just simply change the coordinates of the player, but I think this might be screwing with the FPSController script.
I am using Unity3d, with Standard Assets imported, All of the code is in C#.

Comment: Try placing print statements in the FPSController script. If it gets called, then the method is still being called. Tell me if the methods are being called.

Comment: I put one in there and it indeed is still getting called.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the Y value of your character, I would instead place a death collider under the map. Make this a trigger and if the player touches this trigger, then teleport them back. Nothing with your code should screw with the FPS controller so it might be something else. I would also highly recommend not using a `FindGameObjectWithTag` in the `Update()` method as it is extremely expensive to use this every frame, especially twice. If you would rather keep the `Update()` Y component of the position check, please rewrite the code to something like this:

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
    // assign this object of your player in the inspector - it stores the reference to reuse
    // instead of grabbing it every frame
    [SerializeField] private Transform playerTransform = null;
    
    // make this a variable as it is not changing - might as well make this const too
    private Vector3 checkpoint = new Vector3(0, 3, 0);
    
    // constant value of what to check for in the Y
    private const int FALL_Y_MARKER = -4;
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (playerTransform.position.y < FALL_Y_MARKER) 
        {
            playerTransform.position = checkpoint;
        }
    }
}
```

With your current code, there should be nothing breaking your input/movement, but with that said, we can not see your input/movement code. All the above snippet does is check if the Y component of the player objects position is below a certain value, and if it is, it sets the position to a new vector. Can you post a bit  more movement code or somewhere else it can go wrong that you think is the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do I assign a tag "playerTransform" to the player object or rename the player object?

Comment: You do not have to do either. What object is this script on? Is it on the player? You just need to drag the player object into the public field. You are going to assign the player [reference in the inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/430/Documentation/Manual/EditingReferenceProperties.html).

Comment: I also do not know if this will fix your issue. I just cleaned up the code so it is more efficient. If it does not fix the issue, I would need to see more of your code, most likely the movement as that is what is breaking.

Comment: I didn't make the movement script, it was part of an asset called "standard assets" I found on the unity store, would it be better if I came up with my own?

Comment: And also no this did not fix my problem, it gives me the following error:
"Transform does not contain any definition for 'y' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform'."

Comment: @Yablu Sorry the snippet had a typo. Should be fixed now.